# Creating a container to store Template Class instantiations

Tags: c++, templates, containers

Suppose I have a template struct:

```
template<typename T>
struct Entity
{
  Entity(int Id) : id(Id) 
  { 
    /* init 'data' */ 
  }
  
  T* data; 
  int id; 
};
```

And then a second class who's role is to store Entities of varying types:

```
typename<Ts...>
class EntityContainer
{
public:
  EntityContainer(Ts... Args)
  {
     /* store 'Args' (which are all template instantiations of entity) in some 'entity container' */
  }

  template<typename T>
  void addNewEntity(T&& entity)
  {
     /* new entities can be added to the 'entity container' at run time */
  }
  
  template<typename T>
  T& getEntityById(int id)
  {
     /* stored Entities must be accessible and mutable at run time */
  }
private:
  /*Entity container goes here e.g. std::tuple<Ts...> */
};
```

These two classes would be used in tandem as show:

```
//create two entities of differing types
Entity<A> myFirstEntity(1);     
Entity<B> mySecondEntity(2);          

//store the entities in a container
EntityContainer<Entity<A>, Entity<B>> myContainer(myFirstEntity, mySecondEntity);

//create a new Entity and add it to the container
Entity<C> myThirdEntity(3);
mycontainer.addNewEntity(myThirdEntity);

//retrieve entity from container at run time
myContainer<Entity<B>>.getEntityById(2);          //should return 'mySecondEntity'
```

So I've been trying to get this working for a while, and I got quite close using an `std::tuple` as the entity container in my `EntityContainer` Class, but the problem is that I was having trouble accessing and mutating specific elements in the `std::tuple` at run time, so I dont think it's fit for the job. Perhaps this is not the correct approach whatsoever, and and inheritance based solution would be more apt, but I cant think of one.

I've tried to make this as clear as possible while also providing sufficient code, I hope this isnt asking too much, just looking for some direction.

Comment: Not to make it sound simpler than it is, but - When you go to explain the real problem, you should leave room for it. Right now, your problem description har nearly no space. It's cramped up at the bottom... Can you make it a signature question instead?

Comment: this looks like a complicated version of entity-component system, you want to have a non-templated entity, usually just an id and some way of identifying what components are attached to this entity, then you have different types of components ( here your data ) that you can attach to your entity to create different types. You want entity to be stored in the container directly not through a pointer so when iterating you dont have indirection like the other suggestions

Comment: Yes but how do you 'attach' components  to your entity? surely at some point you would need a container which is owned by the entity which holds components of different types

Comment: Components are stored in another container, entity just has an index into that container for example

Answer (score 2):

> inheritance based solution would be more apt, but I cant think of one.

Make `Entity` a sub-class of a regular class and store pointers to the base class.

```
struct EntityBase
{
   virtual ~EntityBase() {}
};

template<typename T>
struct Entity : EntityBase
{
   ...
};
```

Now, `EntityContainer` can store pointers, preferably smart pointers, to `EntityBase`.

Answer (score 1):

In some sense your question is similar to "How can I store `std::vector<int>`s and `std::string`s and `foo`s in the same container?". Different instantiations of the same template are different types. Not necessarily have they anything in common (other than being instantiations of the same template of course).

The short answer is: You cannot. A container can only hold elements of one type.

However, there are types that can take values of multiple types. There is `std::any` or `std::variant`. A keyword to read more is "type-erasure".

Perhaps you know type-erasure in the form of run-time polymorphism which is probably the most easy to grasp incarnation. Instead of storing the actual type in the container you store pointers (perferably smart ones) to a base class in the container.

I will only outline the approach:

```
struct EntityBase {
    // declare interface here
    virtual ~EntityBase() {}
};

template <typename T>
struct Entity : EntityBase {
    T* data;
};

std::vector<std::shared_ptr<EntityBase>> entities;
```

The easy case is when the interface does not depend on `T`, ie you never need to cast or know what is the dynamic type of the elements.

Comment: Ok that looks promising, the problem comes  when you have a method in `EntityBase` which needs access to `data` in `Entity`, is that correct? E.g a method  with signature: `virtual T* getData()` ... obviously `T` would mean nothing to this function. Is there any way around that?

Comment: @jf192210 No, you would put all stuff that is independent of the template parameter in the base class and only that. Look into `std::variant` and `std::visit` then, unfortunately I cannot tell you much about it. Though, similar questions are asked frequently, if you search a bit you should find more answers

Comment: No problem, you've put me in the right direction, that's all that I could ask for :)

Comment: @jf192210 this looks like a nice introduction. I didn't read it but it seems to be quite exhaustive https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/

Comment: @jf192210 btw `std::tuple` is a product type. The set of values is the product of the sets of possible values of the types, you rather need a so called sum type. A sum types set of possible values is the union of all possible values of the individual types. Hope that makes any sense. What I mean is a `std::tuple<int,double>` contains a string and a double, a `std::variant<int,double>` contains a `int` or a `double`, you want the latter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221707/discussion-between-jf192210-and-idclev-463035818).

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented something similar to this in one of my recent projects. This is the most common way that I have come across so far.
To do this, we need to have 3 basic objects,

```cpp
/**
 * This class will be used as the base class of the actual container.
 */
class ContainerBase {
public:
    ContainerBase() {}
    virtual ~ContainerBase() {}
};

/**
 * This class will hold the actual data.
 */
template<class TYPE>
class Container : public ContainerBase {
public:
    Container() {}
    ~Container() {}

    std::vector<TYPE> data;
};

/**
 * This is the class which is capable of holding all the types of objects with different types.
 * It can store multiple objects of the same time since we are using a dynamic array (std::vector<>).
 */
class EntityContainer {
public:
    EntityContainer() {}
    ~EntityContainer() {}

private:
    std::vector<std::string> registeredTypes;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ContainerBase*> containerMap;
};
```

Then we must define a few methods to add data. But in order to add data to the container, we must first register it.

```cpp
class EntityContainer {
public:
    EntityContainer() {}
    ~EntityContainer()
    {
        // Make sure to delete all the allocated memory!
        for (auto containerPair : containerMap)
            delete containerPair.second;
    }

    /**
     * Check is the required object type is registered by iterating through the registered types.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    bool isRegistered()
    {
        for (auto& type : registeredTypes)
            if (type == typeid(TYPE).name())
                return true;

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Register a new type.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    void registerType()
    {
        // Return if the type is already available.
        if (isRegistered<TYPE>())
            return;

        std::string type = typeid(TYPE).name();

        containerMap[type] = new Container<TYPE>;
        registeredTypes.push_back(type);
    }

    /**
     * Get the container of the required type.
     * This method returns an empty container if the required type is not registered.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    Container<TYPE>* getContainer()
    {
        if (!isRegistered<TYPE>())
            registerType<TYPE>();

        return dynamic_cast<Container<TYPE>*>(containerMap[typeid(TYPE).name()]);
    }

    /**
     * Add a new entity to the TYPE container.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    void addNewEntity(TYPE&& data)
    {
        getContainer<TYPE>()->data.push_back(std::move(data));
    }

    /**
     * Get a data which is stored in the container of the required type using its ID.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    TYPE getEntityByID(int ID)
    {
        std::vector<TYPE> tempVec = getContainer<TYPE>()->data;

        for (auto entity : tempVec)
            if (entity.id == ID)
                return entity;

        return TYPE();
    }
        getContainer<TYPE>()->data.push_back(data);
    }

    /**
     * Get a data which is stored in the container of the required type using its index.
     */
    template<class TYPE>
    TYPE getData(size_t index)
    {
        return getContainer<TYPE>()->data[index];
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::string> registeredTypes;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, ContainerBase*> containerMap;
};
```

Now using the above data structure, you can accomplish your task.

```cpp
//store the entities in a container
EntityContainer container;

Entity<A> myFirstEntity(1);     
Entity<B> mySecondEntity(2);          
Entity<C> myThirdEntity(3);

mycontainer.addNewEntity(myFirstEntity);
mycontainer.addNewEntity(mySecondEntity);
mycontainer.addNewEntity(myThirdEntity);

mycontainer.getEntityByID<Entity<C>>(3);
```

This structure can hold almost any type of object. The only drawback here is that you need to know the type at compile time. But still there are plenty of ways to extend this structure to fit your needs.

Comment: You've given me a lot to look at thanks :) It looks very promising

Comment: @jf192210 Anytime ;)

Answer (score 0):

Heterogeneous container implementation:

```
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include<experimental/type_traits>


// ### heterogeneous container ###

namespace container
{
template<class...>
struct type_list{};

template<class... TYPES>
struct visitor_base
{
    using types = container::type_list<TYPES...>;
};

struct entity_container
{
public:
    entity_container() = default;

    template<typename ...Ts>
    entity_container(Ts ...args)
    {
        auto loop = [&](auto& arg)
        {
            this->push_back(arg);
        };
        (loop(args), ...);
    }

    entity_container(const entity_container& _other)
    {
        *this = _other;
    }

    entity_container& operator=(const entity_container& _other)
    {
        clear();
        clear_functions = _other.clear_functions;
        copy_functions = _other.copy_functions;
        size_functions = _other.size_functions;
        stored_ids_functions = _other.stored_ids_functions; 
        id_delete_functions = _other.id_delete_functions;
        
        for (auto&& copy_function : copy_functions)
        {
            copy_function(_other, *this);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    void push_back(const T& _t)
    {
        //is a new container being made? if so ...
        if (items<T>.find(this) == std::end(items<T>)) 
        {
            clear_functions.emplace_back([](entity_container& _c){items<T>.erase(&_c);});
            id_delete_functions.emplace_back([&](entity_container& _c, int id)
            {
                for(auto& ent : items<T>[&_c])
                {
                    if(ent.getId() == id)
                        items<T>[&_c].erase( std::find(items<T>[&_c].begin(), items<T>[&_c].end(), ent) );
                }   
            });
            copy_functions.emplace_back([](const entity_container& _from, entity_container& _to)
            {
                items<T>[&_to] = items<T>[&_from];
            });
            size_functions.emplace_back([](const entity_container& _c){return items<T>[&_c].size();}); //returns the size of the vector
            stored_ids_functions.emplace_back([](const entity_container& _c)
            {
                std::vector<int> stored_ids; 
                for(auto& ent : items<T>[&_c])
                    stored_ids.push_back(ent.getId());
                return stored_ids;
            });
        }
        items<T>[this].push_back(_t);
    }

    void clear()
    {
        for (auto&& clear_func : clear_functions)
        {
            clear_func(*this);
        }
    }

    template<class T>
    size_t number_of() const
    {
        auto iter = items<T>.find(this);
        if (iter != items<T>.cend())
            return items<T>[this].size();
        return 0;
    }

    size_t size() const
    {
        size_t sum = 0;
        for (auto&& size_func : size_functions)
            sum += size_func(*this);
        // gotta be careful about this overflowing
        return sum;
    }

    bool exists_by_id(int id) const
    {
        for(auto&& id_func : stored_ids_functions) //visit each of the id functions
        {
            std::vector<int> ids = id_func(*this);
            auto res = std::find(std::begin(ids), std::end(ids), id);
            if(res != std::end(ids))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    } 

    void delete_by_id(int id)
    {
        for(auto&& id_delete_func : id_delete_functions)
            id_delete_func(*this, id);
    }

    void print_stored_ids()
    {
        for(auto&& id_func : stored_ids_functions) //visit each of the id functions
        {
            std::vector<int> ids = id_func(*this);
            for(auto& id : ids)
                std::cout << "id: " << id << std::endl;
        }
    }
    ~entity_container()
    {
        clear();
    }

    template<class T>
    void visit(T&& visitor)
    {
        visit_impl(visitor, typename std::decay_t<T>::types{});
    }

private:
    template<class T>
    static std::unordered_map<const entity_container*, std::vector<T>> items;

    template<class T, class U>
    using visit_function = decltype(std::declval<T>().operator()(std::declval<U&>()));

    template<class T, class U>
    static constexpr bool has_visit_v = std::experimental::is_detected<visit_function, T, U>::value;

    template<class T, template<class...> class TLIST, class... TYPES>
    void visit_impl(T&& visitor, TLIST<TYPES...>)
    {
        (..., visit_impl_help<std::decay_t<T>, TYPES>(visitor));
    }

    template<class T, class U>
    void visit_impl_help(T& visitor)
    {
        static_assert(has_visit_v<T, U>, "Visitors must provide a visit function accepting a reference for each type");
        for (auto&& element : items<U>[this])
        {
            visitor(element);
        }
    }
    std::vector<std::function<void(entity_container&)>> clear_functions;
    std::vector<std::function<void(const entity_container&, entity_container&)>> copy_functions;
    std::vector<std::function<size_t(const entity_container&)>> size_functions;
    std::vector<std::function<std::vector<int>(const entity_container&)>> stored_ids_functions;
    std::vector<std::function<void(entity_container&, int)>> id_delete_functions;
};

template<class T>
std::unordered_map<const entity_container*, std::vector<T>> entity_container::items;
}
```

Use:

```
template<class T>
struct Entity
{
public:
    Entity(int Id) : id(Id) 
    {
        data = new T();
    }

    bool operator==(const Entity<T>& rhs) const {
        return (this->id == rhs.id && this->data == rhs.data);
    }

    int getId(){return id;}
    T*& getData(){ return data; }

private:
    int id;
    T* data;
};

struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

 /* ## main ## */


int main()
{
    
    Entity<A> entity_a(1);
    Entity<B> entity_b(2);
    Entity<C> entity_c(3);
    Entity<C> entity_d(10);

    container::entity_container c(entity_a, entity_b, entity_c);
    c.push_back(entity_d);

    c.print_stored_ids(); //prints the id's of all store entities

    c.delete_by_id(3);    //deletes the store entities with the parsed id
    c.delete_by_id(1);
    c.delete_by_id(10);

    c.print_stored_ids();
}
```

Largely sourced from https://gieseanw.wordpress.com/2017/05/03/a-true-heterogeneous-container-in-c/ with some personal additions to adapt the container for Type such as `Entity` (i.e with an ID and a pointer to some data). Might be useful to someone.